# How to insert exe file in VB.NET project and publish app with this file?

Tags: vb.net

I want to add exe file and run this file from my  VB.NET application. I tried to add it in project folder and run it like "Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "/file.exe") and it work in debug mode, but when i publish this application and run it, it can not find this "file.exe". Pls help.

Comment: you need to distribute the exe with your app see these duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vb.net+resource+exe

Comment: Does it get included in the published copy if you first select the exe in the project explorer and set the **Copy to Output Directory** property to **Copy always** or **Copy if newer**?

Comment: How are you publishing it? You should just add it to your installer.

Comment: i pulished it like Build>Publish

Comment: It works now, tnx Steven Doggart , i just changed Copy to Output Directory property to Copy always

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the file to your program resources (by using `import`).

Then, you can use this code:

```
Process.Start(My.Resources.ResourceManager.BaseName+"/filename.exe")
```